# Cannot connect intkey Tp to sawtooth test network

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to set up a multi node sawtooth netwrok using sawtooth 1.2. I tested the docker compose file with the default intkey containers and it worked.

But when I tried to set up intkey using the NodeJs SDK and tried to connect to the validator, the connection is not responded. Also when I try to browse the http://localhost:8008/batches, the url is unreachable.

docker-compose file

```
version: "2.1"

volumes:
  poet-shared:

services:
  shell:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-shell-default
    entrypoint: "bash -c \"\
        sawtooth keygen && \
        tail -f /dev/null \
        \""

  validator-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    volumes:
      - poet-shared:/poet-shared
    command: "bash -c \"\
        sawadm keygen --force && \
        mkdir -p /poet-shared/validator-0 || true && \
        cp -a /etc/sawtooth/keys /poet-shared/validator-0/ && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet.batch ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        cp /poet-shared/poet.batch / && \
        sawset genesis \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          -o config-genesis.batch && \
        sawset proposal create \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name=PoET \
          sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=0.1 \
          sawtooth.poet.report_public_key_pem=\
          \\\"$$(cat /poet-shared/simulator_rk_pub.pem)\\\" \
          sawtooth.poet.valid_enclave_measurements=$$(cat /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement) \
          sawtooth.poet.valid_enclave_basenames=$$(cat /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename) \
          -o config.batch && \
        sawset proposal create \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
             sawtooth.poet.target_wait_time=5 \
             sawtooth.poet.initial_wait_time=25 \
             sawtooth.publisher.max_batches_per_block=100 \
          -o poet-settings.batch && \
        sawadm genesis \
          config-genesis.batch config.batch poet.batch poet-settings.batch && \
        sawtooth-validator -v \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --peering static \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --network-auth trust
    \""
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "/project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/common:\
        /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/simulator:\
        /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/core"
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  validator-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-1
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    volumes:
      - poet-shared:/poet-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawadm keygen --force && \
        mkdir -p /poet-shared/validator-1 || true && \
        cp -a /etc/sawtooth/keys /poet-shared/validator-1/ && \
        sawtooth-validator -v \
            --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
            --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
            --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
            --peering static \
            --endpoint tcp://validator-1:8800 \
            --peers tcp://validator-0:8800 \
            --scheduler parallel \
            --network-auth trust
      "
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "/project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/common:\
        /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/simulator:\
        /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/core"
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  rest-api-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-0
    expose:
      - 8008
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-0:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-0:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  rest-api-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-1
    expose:
      - 9008
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-1:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-1:9008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  settings-tp-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -v -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  settings-tp-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-1
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -v -C tcp://validator-1:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  poet-engine-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-poet-engine:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-poet-engine-0
    volumes:
      - poet-shared:/poet-shared
    command: "bash -c \"\
        if [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement ]; then \
            poet enclave measurement >> /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement; \
        fi && \
        if [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename ]; then \
            poet enclave basename >> /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename; \
        fi && \
        if [ ! -f /poet-shared/simulator_rk_pub.pem ]; then \
            cp /etc/sawtooth/simulator_rk_pub.pem /poet-shared; \
        fi && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/validator-0/keys/validator.priv ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        cp -a /poet-shared/validator-0/keys /etc/sawtooth && \
        poet registration create -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv -o /poet-shared/poet.batch && \
        poet-engine -C tcp://validator-0:5050 --component tcp://validator-0:4004 \
    \""

  poet-engine-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-poet-engine:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-poet-engine-1
    volumes:
      - poet-shared:/poet-shared
    command: "bash -c \"\
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/validator-1/keys/validator.priv ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        cp -a /poet-shared/validator-1/keys /etc/sawtooth && \
        poet-engine -C tcp://validator-1:5050 --component tcp://validator-1:4004 \
    \""

  poet-validator-registry-tp-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-poet-validator-registry-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-poet-validator-registry-tp-0
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: poet-validator-registry-tp -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/common
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  poet-validator-registry-tp-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-poet-validator-registry-tp:chime
    container_name: sawtooth-poet-validator-registry-tp-1
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: poet-validator-registry-tp -C tcp://validator-1:4004
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/common
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
```

intkey handler

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Intel Corporation
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

'use strict'

const { TransactionHandler } = require('sawtooth-sdk/processor/handler')
const {
  InvalidTransaction,
  InternalError
} = require('sawtooth-sdk/processor/exceptions')

const crypto = require('crypto')
const cbor = require('cbor')

// Constants defined in intkey specification
const MIN_VALUE = 0
const MAX_VALUE = 4294967295
const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 20

const _hash = (x) =>
  crypto.createHash('sha512').update(x).digest('hex').toLowerCase()

const INT_KEY_FAMILY = 'intkey'
const INT_KEY_NAMESPACE = _hash(INT_KEY_FAMILY).substring(0, 6)

const _decodeCbor = (buffer) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    cbor.decodeFirst(buffer, (err, obj) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(obj)))
  )

const _toInternalError = (err) => {
  let message = (err.message) ? err.message : err
  throw new InternalError(message)
}

const _setEntry = (context, address, stateValue) => {
  let entries = {
    [address]: cbor.encode(stateValue)
  }
  return context.setState(entries)
}

const _applySet = (context, address, name, value) => (possibleAddressValues) => {
  let stateValueRep = possibleAddressValues[address]

  let stateValue
  if (stateValueRep && stateValueRep.length > 0) {
    stateValue = cbor.decodeFirstSync(stateValueRep)
    let stateName = stateValue[name]
    if (stateName) {
      throw new InvalidTransaction(
        `Verb is "set" but Name already in state, Name: ${name} Value: ${stateName}`
      )
    }
  }

  // 'set' passes checks so store it in the state
  if (!stateValue) {
    stateValue = {}
  }

  stateValue[name] = value

  return _setEntry(context, address, stateValue)
}

const _applyOperator = (verb, op) => (context, address, name, value) => (possibleAddressValues) => {
  let stateValueRep = possibleAddressValues[address]
  if (!stateValueRep || stateValueRep.length === 0) {
    throw new InvalidTransaction(`Verb is ${verb} but Name is not in state`)
  }

  let stateValue = cbor.decodeFirstSync(stateValueRep)
  if (stateValue[name] === null || stateValue[name] === undefined) {
    throw new InvalidTransaction(`Verb is ${verb} but Name is not in state`)
  }

  const result = op(stateValue[name], value)

  if (result < MIN_VALUE) {
    throw new InvalidTransaction(
      `Verb is ${verb}, but result would be less than ${MIN_VALUE}`
    )
  }

  if (result > MAX_VALUE) {
    throw new InvalidTransaction(
      `Verb is ${verb}, but result would be greater than ${MAX_VALUE}`
    )
  }

  // Increment the value in state by value
  // stateValue[name] = op(stateValue[name], value)
  stateValue[name] = result
  return _setEntry(context, address, stateValue)
}

const _applyInc = _applyOperator('inc', (x, y) => x + y)
const _applyDec = _applyOperator('dec', (x, y) => x - y)

class IntegerKeyHandler extends TransactionHandler {
  constructor () {
    super(INT_KEY_FAMILY, ['1.0'], [INT_KEY_NAMESPACE])
  }

  apply (transactionProcessRequest, context) {
    return _decodeCbor(transactionProcessRequest.payload)
      .catch(_toInternalError)
      .then((update) => {
        //
        // Validate the update
        let name = update.Name
        if (!name) {
          throw new InvalidTransaction('Name is required')
        }

        if (name.length > MAX_NAME_LENGTH) {
          throw new InvalidTransaction(
            `Name must be a string of no more than ${MAX_NAME_LENGTH} characters`
          )
        }

        let verb = update.Verb
        if (!verb) {
          throw new InvalidTransaction('Verb is required')
        }

        let value = update.Value
        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
          throw new InvalidTransaction('Value is required')
        }

        let parsed = parseInt(value)
        if (parsed !== value || parsed < MIN_VALUE || parsed > MAX_VALUE) {
          throw new InvalidTransaction(
            `Value must be an integer ` +
            `no less than ${MIN_VALUE} and ` +
            `no greater than ${MAX_VALUE}`)
        }

        value = parsed

        // Determine the action to apply based on the verb
        let actionFn
        if (verb === 'set') {
          actionFn = _applySet
        } else if (verb === 'dec') {
          actionFn = _applyDec
        } else if (verb === 'inc') {
          actionFn = _applyInc
        } else {
          throw new InvalidTransaction(`Verb must be set, inc, dec not ${verb}`)
        }

        let address = INT_KEY_NAMESPACE + _hash(name).slice(-64)

        // Get the current state, for the key's address:
        let getPromise = context.getState([address])

        // Apply the action to the promise's result:
        let actionPromise = getPromise.then(
          actionFn(context, address, name, value)
        )

        // Validate that the action promise results in the correctly set address:
        return actionPromise.then(addresses => {
          if (addresses.length === 0) {
            throw new InternalError('State Error!')
          }
          console.log(`Verb: ${verb} Name: ${name} Value: ${value}`)
        })
      })
  }
}

module.exports = IntegerKeyHandler
```

intkey index

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Intel Corporation
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

'use strict'

const { TransactionProcessor } = require('sawtooth-sdk/processor')
const IntegerKeyHandler = require('./handler')

const address = "tcp://localhost:4004";

const transactionProcessor = new TransactionProcessor(address)

transactionProcessor.addHandler(new IntegerKeyHandler())

transactionProcessor.start()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by forwarding the ports in rest-api and validator containers:

But I am still unable to successfully submit transactions. the transactions remains pending.

```
const {createContext, CryptoFactory} = require('sawtooth-sdk/signing')
const cbor = require('cbor')
const {createHash} = require('crypto')
const {protobuf} = require('sawtooth-sdk')
const crypto = require('crypto')

// Creating a Private Key and Signer
const context = createContext('secp256k1')
const privateKey = context.newRandomPrivateKey()
const signer = new CryptoFactory(context).newSigner(privateKey)
const _hash = (x) => crypto.createHash('sha512').update(x).digest('hex').toLowerCase()


// Encoding Your Payload
const payload = {
    Verb: 'set',
    Name: 'foo',
    Value: 25
}
const payloadBytes = cbor.encode(payload)

let familyAddr = _hash('intkey').substring(0, 6);
let nameAddr = _hash(payload.Name).slice(-64);
let addr = familyAddr + nameAddr;
console.log(addr);


// Create the Transaction Header
const transactionHeaderBytes = protobuf.TransactionHeader.encode({
    familyName: 'intkey',
    familyVersion: '1.0',
    inputs: [addr],
    outputs: [addr],
    signerPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    batcherPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    dependencies: [],
    payloadSha512: createHash('sha512').update(payloadBytes).digest('hex')
}).finish()

// Create the Transaction
const signature = signer.sign(transactionHeaderBytes)
const transaction = protobuf.Transaction.create({
    header: transactionHeaderBytes,
    headerSignature: signature,
    payload: payloadBytes
})

//  Create the BatchHeader
const transactions = [transaction]
const batchHeaderBytes = protobuf.BatchHeader.encode({
    signerPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    transactionIds: transactions.map((txn) => txn.headerSignature),
}).finish()

// Create the Batch
const headerSignature = signer.sign(batchHeaderBytes)
const batch = protobuf.Batch.create({
    header: batchHeaderBytes,
    headerSignature: headerSignature,
    transactions: transactions
})

// Encode the Batch(es) in a BatchList
const batchListBytes = protobuf.BatchList.encode({
    batches: [batch]
}).finish()

// Submitting Batches to the Validator
const request = require('request')
request.post({
    url: 'http://localhost:8008/batches',
    body: batchListBytes,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(response.body)
})
```